# How to bind a function in ReactJS with optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, bind, flowtype

Let's say I've got a function I need to bind in the React component constructor because it will be passed down as props to the child component.

The function has one optional parameter that has a default value if none is specified. What is the syntax for binding this kind of function?

Let's say I've got a function with an optional paramter that has a default value if none is specified:

```
_handleEdit(isTwoWay: boolean = false):void {}
```

What's the syntax for doing that in the declaration?

```
class Component extends React.Component<void, void, void> {

    _handleEdit: (isTwoWay: boolean = false) => void;

    constructor(): void {
        super();

        this._handleEdit = this._handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    _handleEdit(isTwoWay: boolean = false): void {
    }

}
```

This syntax does not pass the flow check or build:
 _handleEdit: (isTwoWay: boolean = false) => void;

Comment: Please, post the code where `this._handleEdit` is set by parent class. Is it a prototype method? This affects the answer.

Comment: It's not a prototype, it's a real method.

Comment: I refer to class `prototype` method, not colloquial meaning. There is a  difference between prototype methods and the methods defined in constructor.

Comment: `_handleEdit: (isTwoWay?: boolean) => void;` should work

Comment: This looks like a bug. https://tryflow.org/?code=LyogQGZsb3cgKi8KCmltcG9ydCBSZWFjdCBmcm9tICdyZWFjdCcKCmNsYXNzIENvbXBvbmVudCBleHRlbmRzIFJlYWN0LkNvbXBvbmVudCB7CiAgICBfaGFuZGxlRWRpdDogKGlzVHdvV2F5OiBib29sZWFuID0gZmFsc2UpID0+IHZvaWQKICAgIAogICAgX2hhbmRsZUVkaXQoaXNUd29XYXk6IGJvb2xlYW4gPSBmYWxzZSkge30KfQoKY29uc3QgaGFuZGxlRWRpdCA9IChpc1R3b1dheTogYm9vbGVhbiA9IGZhbHNlKSA9PiB7fQ== Why should the class property annotation not work when the other two do?